# How to select last sentence from a column, which is starting from a number

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I want to get the last sentence that is starting from a number in a column.

**Example Code:**

```
WITH q AS (SELECT '1.abc def ghi 2.sdadasd. rewtretrtr1 3. hjgjhjhgj, yo whats. 4. gog mi man. Its been' AS sentence FROM DUAL)
SELECT SUBSTR(sentence, INSTR(sentence,'.',-1) + 1)
FROM q;
```

**My Output**

```
Its been
```

**Expected Output**

```
4. gog mi man. Its been
```

Is this possible in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for [handy Oracle regexp function `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(sentence, '\d\.\D+$') FROM q;
```

Regexp breakdown:

```
\d   -- a digit
\.   -- a dot
\D+  -- as many non-digit characters as possible (at least one)
$    -- end of string
```

`REGEXP_SUBSTR()` searches the string for a for the given regular expression and returns a given occurence (first occurence by default).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52db27f6478c5b863c7e7c84e5cb3a37)**:

```
WITH q AS (SELECT '1.abc def ghi 2.sdadasd. rewtretrtr1 3. hjgjhjhgj, yo whats. 4. gog mi man. Its been' AS sentence FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(sentence, '\d\.\D+$') FROM q;
```

```
| REGEXP_SUBSTR(SENTENCE,'\D\.\D+$') |
| :--------------------------------- |
| 4. gog mi man. Its been            |
```

---

**EDIT**

It turns out that you are dealing with much more complex strings:

- the portion to capture might contain numbers
- the string may contain new line

I hence would suggest a new approach, that relies on `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove the unwanted part of the string.

Consider:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(sentence, '.*\d+\.', '', 1, 0, 'n') FROM q;
```

Regexp `.*\d+\.` will greadily match everything from the beginning of the string to the last occurence of a digit followed by a dot and a space. `REGEXP_REPLACE` will suppress that part of the string. The `'n'` modifier allows the `.` character to match on the new line character.

With this expression, you get the expected part of the string, only minus the digit(s) and dot at the beginning (that's as good as it gets, since Oracle does not support regex lookaheads... sigh).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f1fa1964832cf89da22585d9dc1db473)**:

Given this input string:

```
We have received customer approval on the 
warranty nozzle including revised ERO repairs. Please proceed with the repairs. 
Please provide photos and damage mapping when complete per customer requests." 9/12/19 MH
10. CHECKING WITH VENDOR ABOUT ECD. 9/13/19 
MH11. Per Vendor,
"Originally I quoted a 3-4 week delivery once approved. This month is shot. W
e are booked solid. We estimate a delivery date of 10/11" 9/13/19 MH
```

The query returns:

```
 Per Vendor,
"Originally I quoted a 3-4 week delivery once approved. This month is shot. W
e are booked solid. We estimate a delivery date of 10/11" 9/13/19 MH
```

Comment: Thanks, man, Is there a documentation for this, what is it called?

Comment: Welcome @StackOne. I added a few explanation and the link to the documentation in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I tried a sample of DB Fiddle, it doesn't work. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=95914d09687f4ecae105036518f68551

Comment: @StackOne: this is quite a different string from what you have shown in your example... What would be your expected results here?

Comment: Here, It would be similar to the question, any sentence that is starting from number, `11. Per Vendor,
"Originally I quoted a 3-4 week delivery once approved. This month is shot. W
e are booked solid. We estimate a delivery date of 10/11" 9/13/19 MH`

Comment: Is it OK if you loose the `11. ` at the beginning of the string to capture?

Comment: Yes, it is okay to loose the number

Comment: How do I change it from the last occurrence to first occurrence? REGEXP_REPLACE(sentence, '.*\d+\.', '', 1, 0, 'n')

Comment: @StackOne: you can't keep changing the requirements... You would need to ask a new question.

Comment: I have asked a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky, if your sentences can contain digits.  But it can be done in Oracle:

```
WITH q AS (
      SELECT '1.abc def ghi 2.sdadasd. rewtretrtr1 3. hjgjhjhgj, yo whats. 4. gog mi man. Its been' AS sentence FROM DUAL union all
      SELECT '1.abc def ghi 2.sdadasd. rewtretrtr1 3. hjgjhjhgj, yo whats. 4. gog mi 3 men. Its been' AS sentence FROM DUAL 
     )
SELECT regexp_substr(sentence, '\d[.](\D|\d+[^.])*$')
FROM q;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Could you explain the reg_exp part of the code? Thanks

Comment: Check this out, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abac8c052c594024aa80c0669da79fc3, I need the output from "11."

Comment: @StackOne . . . Does the other answer work for this?  You accepted it.